Form field containing list of Enum
I have a form field containing a list of Enum.
I don't know how to populate it via React Hook Form :
type Form = {
   enums : Enum[]
}

export default function MyComponent() {

    const { control, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm<Form>()
    const enums: Enum[] = Object.values(Enum);

    return (
       {enums.map(enum => 
                    <Controller
                        control={control}
                        name="enums"
                        render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
                            <>
                                <Text>{value}</Text>
                                <CustomButton title={enum} onChange={onChange}/>
                            </>
                        )}
                    />
       )}

    ...);

What I want :
When I click on the CustomButton so an enum (associated to this button) is added or removed.
I am very stucked
